# Adding extra double quotes to existing cell contents in macro search/replace in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am programitically trying to simulate the excel "Find and Replace" functionality, I have certain doubts/concerns in doing so. Below is the code I am using and was recorded using the 'Record Macro' feature in excel.

```
 Selection.Replace What:=":Y", Replacement:="helloWorld", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

In the above code, if I were to replace helloWorld with something like This is a "Chicken" The code would fail miserably because of the "This is a "Chicken"" situation. To correct it we should have something like "This is a ""Chicken"""

However the text to replace is coming from a cell in the same excel sheet. How can add an extra quotes to text that have a quote already to avoid any errors.

Same goes for special chars like $%^&*!@#

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the replacement text is coming from the value of another cell, I wouldn't worry about doing a string conversion at all. What I'd be inclined to do is pass the .Value property of the cell containing the replacement text to the Replacement:= argument of the Replace method. That way Excel will take care of all the quotation and other characters internally; you won't have to worry about it.

Something like this:

```
Sub ReplaceText()

On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear

    'Let's say that the replacement text is in A1
    Selection.Replace What:=":Y", Replacement:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

    'In case it's something like an error in the replacement text cell.
    'Using quotes or special characters WON'T cause an error.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Replacement failed; error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End If

On Error GoTo 0


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Alan, one more question - say I want to replace a text with a paragraph of 2 lines (separated by a blank line in between). If the replacement cell has text in paragraph manner, would the same be replicated in find and replace?

Comment: Sorry, by the time you asked that it was bed time here. Yes, if you mean that the replacement cell contains a line break of the kind that you get by typing line1 [Alt]+[Enter] line2 into a cell, it'll handle that as well. Like I said, all of the formatting codes are embedded in the .Value property and handled within Excel; you don't need to translate them to text to pass into the Replacement argument. The only time you'll have a problem is where the replacement cell contains something that can't evaluate to a string (such as =6/0, say) which is why the error handler is wrapped around it.

Comment: I should have added... while it'll do the find and replace correctly for a multi-line cell, the one thing that it WON'T do is automatically resize the cell(s) that the replacement is done in to show the extra "lines". But that's always been an issue with Excel find and replace anyway. You could add a Selection.Rows.AutoFit line if you thought that would be an issue. (Do it after the If Err.Number block, to prevent it from obscuring any errors from the Replace method.)